# Spring Data Rest Frontend deep linking

Tags: frontend, spring-data-rest, hateoas

So i have been struggling with this one question some time now:

How to handle details Page or deep linking on the Frontend.

So, say, we got a paged collection endpoint with user entities in it and a React App consuming the endpoint.
The flow would be, user authenticates, gets collections, clicks on an item and is either:

1. Redirected to a new Url say: webapp.com/users/userid
2. A modal opens with the user details.

Say we got a scenario were two people working with the webapp, Person 1 wants to share a link with Person 2. Person 2 should do some updates on a specific user, which is identified by the link. 
The link should be something like : https://www.webapp.com/users/{slug or id} 
With Option 2 this functionality is not mappable. 
With Option 1 we got to expose the ids in the response to identify the resource, which may work, but we would still need to hardcode the url, as the findById method is not exported as a Uri Template. 
So, my Solution would be to add a slug for the resources, implement a search method by the slug, and then get the user, if found, by its self-link. 
Sounds like a good solution for me, but on the other hand, I would have to add an extra frontend id(the slug here) which would need to be also unique, to the database model.

So how do you guys handle a problem like this, or is there anybody using spring data rest in this way or in production mode where you have the handle situations like this?

Should mention that this isn’t a primary problem with spring data rest but rather with hateoas itself.

thanks in advance 
Florian

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hardcode URL template. Spring data rest will generate links for each resource.

You can refer to it from front end by some format like: `{your_user_object}._links.self.href`

Comment: Yeah i know that much. 
Consider a case where a the frontend has a deep link like so: http://frontend.com/user/1 or http://frontend.com/users/marknote 
the backend link would then be something like http://backend.com/users/1 
so when the user bookmarks the frontend link, how should this be handeld if he revisits the app? 
Then we dont have a user object where we just can get the link and retrive the user. we would only have the slug or the id (if we expose it) and would need to build the link manually, as sdr for example doesnt export a uri template with the id.